# Perforce (2019): Files marked for delete, but associated Workspace/Changelist no longer available

Tags: perforce

I have a bit of a curious problem I've never run into before.
A student of mine deleted a depot from the workspace, but did not submit the changes. He then subsequently deleted his workspace (and all associated changelists). So this is now our situation:

[marked for delete on depot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKvBF.png)

[Workspace files marked for delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7AEd.png)

How can I clean up this tag?

1) I replicated the work directory on another drive, deleted the workspace files (and submitted, deleting them off the depot as well).
2) Copied all the files from the backup, marked for add, then resubmitted
 RESULT: They came back, still tagged for deletion.

I tried reverting individual files and entire directories (no luck).

I can't revert to a prior changelist, as the changelist in question is still pending.

Any ideas on how I can clean this up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi alkangart. I suggest you dereference "your situation" with some descriptive info in your post. Instead of  making the responders use links to see what's going on.

Comment: Cheers, thanks! First time posting here, so just learning the etiquette. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the user actually deleted their client.  Run `p4 opened -a` on the file(s) in question to see what client they're open on:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 opened -a //depot/...
//depot/main/bleh#1 - delete default change (text) by Samwise@classic
```

I can see in this output that the file is opened for delete on the client `classic`.  Does that workspace still exist?

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 clients -e classic
Client classic 2020/03/24 root c:\Perforce\test\depot 'Created by Samwise. '
```

Yes it does.  Can I delete it?  Yes, as long as I'm an administrator:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 client -d classic
Client 'classic' has files opened. To delete the client, revert any opened files and delete any pending changes first. An administrator may specify -f to force the delete of another user's client.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 client -d -f classic
Client classic deleted.
```

Is the file still open?

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 opened -a //depot/...
//depot/... - file(s) not opened anywhere.
```

No it is not.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you. Will try that tonight. :)

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much for that. :) Thanks for walking me through it. Stay safe.